# Wordpress: How to display post count in author page by custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to display the custom taxonomy in author page with a counter but seems i don't know how to do it.

i have a code in *function.php*

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {

    if( !is_admin() && $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_author() ) {

        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 100 );
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'custom_feedback' );

    }

});
```

and in my author page :

```
<div class="feedback-respond"> 
         <h3 class="feedback-title">User Feedback </h3>
             <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
               <?php the_content(); ?>
             <?php endwhile; else: ?>
               <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>
             <?php endif; ?> 
            </div>
```

The code works for all the author profile but i don't know how to get the the custom taxonomy to display like this:

**User Feedback**

*6 POSITIVE feedback 4 NEGATIVE feedback*

all feedback goes here

all feedback goes here

all feedback goes here

By the way it is a custom post type (custom_feedback)and custom taxonomy(feedback_taxonomy) with two category Positive and Negative.

Please help masters?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Comment: but it is not custom fields it is custom taxonomy in author.php displayed.

Comment: Let me Google that for you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10175/how-to-display-custom-taxonomies-in-posts

Comment: Just to be clear and in order to answer your question :-), one post can only have one term assigned to it, either `positive` or `negative`. If you have 10 posts, you need to know how many posts belongs to `negative` and how many belongs to `positive`.

Comment: @odedta your comments makes no sense at all. You are on a wild goose case. This is really easy, and I will properly answer this later based on the OP feedback

Comment: @PieterGoosen  All he's looking for are functions to get custom post types and custom taxonomies, and I provided him with just that. All he needs to do is use the functions so he can print those values.

Comment: @PieterGoosen for example have 10 post and 6 is positive and 4 is negative how may i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only way to acvieve this will be to run two separate queries and counting the posts returned from the two separate queries. For this we will use `get_posts` as `get_posts` already passes a few important defaults to `WP_Query` to make the query faster and more performance orientated.

We will add one huge time and resource saver to the query, `'fields' => 'ids'`. What this does is, it fetches only the post ids, and not the complete post object. This can cut query time and db queries by 99%, so even though you are going to run 2 separate queries on the complete database, the loss in page performance will be unnoticable.

Lets put everything in code (*This goes into author.php, and note, this code is untested and needs at least PHP 5.4+*)

```
$author_id = get_queried_object_id(); // Gets the author id when viewing the author page

// Add our term slugs into an array. 
$terms = ['positive', 'negative']; // Just make sure these values are correct
$count = [];
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    // Build our query
    $args = [
        'nopaging' => true,
        'post_type' => 'custom_feedback',
        'author' => $author_id,
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'feedback_taxonomy',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term
            ],
        ],
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );

    // Count the amount of posts and add in array
    $count[$term] = count( $q );
}

// Display our text with post counts, just make sure your array keys correspond with your term slugs used
$positive = ( isset( $count['positive'] ) ) ? $count['positive'] : 0;
$negative =( isset( $count['negative'] ) ) ? $count['negative'] : 0;

echo $positive . ' POSITIVE feedback ' . $negative . ' NEGATIVE feedback';
```

Comment: works perfect. thanks you so much @PieterGoosen. Can i ask one more thing? is there a way to modify the the_content()? I would like to add a css class to negative and positive taxonomy.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it works. Yes, that can be done. You should start a new question for this though :-)