# Wordpress Custom post type_show post counts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I am working in a custom WP theme.I need to show each posts under individual categories, which is working fine.

I changed the category to taxonomy.Now, i want to show more info under each category name,but, i cannot understand,where should i put my code in the loop.
Specially the post counts under each categories.

```
 <?php
    /*
    Template Name: Home Page
    */
    get_header();
     global $redux_demo;

    ?>
    <div class="sroll"><div class="container">
    <marquee><p> <?php echo $redux_demo['main-option-marquee']; ?></p></marquee>
    </div></div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9"> </br>
      <div class="content mCustomScrollbar" style="height: 690px;">

        <?php
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );
    foreach($terms as $cat){
        $cata_name = $cat->name; 
        $term_id = $cat->term_id; 

    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p10">
    <div class="box">
         <?php 
    //echo '<h3>'.$catname[0]->cat_name.'</h3>';

    ?><h3><a href="<?php echo home_url('index.php/category/'.$cata_name) ?>">
        <?php echo $cata_name; ?></a></h3> <?php

    $catqueryy = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$term_id.'&posts_per_page=4' ); 
    while($catqueryy->have_posts()) : $catqueryy->the_post();
    ?>

        <p class="post_title"><?php echo '<a  href="'.home_url('index.php/category/'.$cata_name).'">'.__(get_the_title(),'rockon').'</a>'; ?></p>
        <p class="post_cont"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <?php
    endwhile; 
    ?>
    </div>

        </div>

    <?php } ?>
    </div></br>
      </div> 

      <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h1></h1>
       <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
      <h1></h1>
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    get_footer();
    ?>
```

Comment: So the code above works, but you do not get the numbers of posts in a term? Or just do not know where to put the number?

Comment: thanks @muka.gergely ,yes code works..But, i don't not know where to put count logic

Comment: I hope I understood well your problem - I suggested a solution, that might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Custom taxonomy try:**

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => TERM_ID
        )
    )
) );
$count = $the_query->found_posts;
```

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/counting-posts-within-categories

**For Example:**

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: Home Page
    */
    get_header();
     global $redux_demo;

    ?>
    <div class="sroll"><div class="container">
    <marquee><p> <?php echo $redux_demo['main-option-marquee']; ?></p></marquee>
    </div></div>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9"> </br>
      <div class="content mCustomScrollbar" style="height: 690px;">

        <?php
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );
    foreach($terms as $cat){
        $cata_name = $cat->name; 
        $term_id = $cat->term_id; 

    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p10">
    <div class="box">
         <?php 
    //echo '<h3>'.$catname[0]->cat_name.'</h3>';

    ?><h3><a href="<?php echo home_url('index.php/category/'.$cata_name) ?>">
        <?php echo $cata_name; ?></a></h3> 
    <?php

    $catqueryy = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$term_id.'&posts_per_page=4' ); 
    $count = $catqueryy->found_posts;
    ?>
    <h3><?php echo "Post Count : ".$count; ?></h3> 
    <?php
    while($catqueryy->have_posts()) : $catqueryy->the_post();
    ?>

        <p class="post_title"><?php echo '<a  href="'.home_url('index.php/category/'.$cata_name).'">'.__(get_the_title(),'rockon').'</a>'; ?></p>
        <p class="post_cont"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <?php
    endwhile; 
    ?>
    </div>

        </div>

    <?php } ?>
    </div></br>
      </div> 

      <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h1></h1>
       <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
      <h1></h1>
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    get_footer();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this Link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097777/wordpress-how-to-display-post-count-in-author-page-by-custom-taxonomy)

if it helps.. I guess, some one will write this code here as I also need to understand how it will work after you pass a query.

Comment: well.i already checked this link.It's not the result i was looking..I am looking simply to display the post count under each categories name.

Comment: @pieter can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need to count anything by manually written code. If you look at the [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) description, you can see that WP counts this for you (if you set 'pad_counts' to true (or 1)). With this turned on there will be a "count" key and a number value in your response array with each category.

You can just "echo" it where you want to.

This way your

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

should look like this:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'pad_counts' => true,
) );
```

Notice that I added **'pad_counts' => true,** to the query, so you will have the number you are looking for - without writing too much code.

If you want to do it manually, I suggest that you create a loop that fills an array with 'category => number' elements, and look up the required key-value pairs in the loop that writes out the HTML.

Comment: Happy to help :) If it gave you the answer you'd been looking for, please vote the answer up ;).

Answer (score -2):

I was also searching for something similar to this question. I think, you need a code to display the post counts of each categories.

Comment: thanks @wpboss, yes, i am very confused about the required code.can you help?